# Embedding Python in a Qt Creator project

Tags: python, qt, numpy, qt-creator, python-c-api

I'm working on a project that requires C++ to call a program written in Python that relies on Python exclusive modules.

The project is handled using Qt Creator, and Python 3.7.5 and its packages are installed via Miniconda. I've gotten a basic embedding working using Pybind11 where basic interfacing works, however, most external modules cannot be imported.

For example, when importing Numpy through Pybind11, the following error is thrown (reduced for brevity):

```
Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.

Original error was: /home/brentnallt/miniconda3/envs/car_class_nogpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyMemoryView_FromObject
```

A similar error occurs when importing tensorflow through Pybind11:

```
ImportError: /home/brentnallt/miniconda3/envs/car_class_nogpu/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicode_FromFormat
```

It appears to be a problem with Python's C API being found when reading C extension shared libraries. However, modules like lxml which use C source files import just fine. Additionally, I can import problem modules in projects separate from the project I'm working on, implying it's a setup problem. Note that this test project setup doesn't actually use any QT functionality, whereas the main one does.

My `PYTHONHOME` environment variable looks like:

```
['/home/brentnallt/miniconda3/envs/car_class_nogpu/lib/python3.7', '/home/brentnallt/miniconda3/envs/car_class_nogpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/home/brentnallt/miniconda3/envs/car_class_nogpu/lib/python37.zip', '/home/brentnallt/miniconda3/envs/car_class_nogpu/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '.']
```

Are there any special considerations I have to make when embedding with Qt Creator? Or is this likely a different problem from a setup error?

Comment: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/numpy.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider using PythonQt as an alternative module for calling and importing python libraries from Qt application.

I've used it a lot in my projects and it never failed, but never used it with any kinda data scientific modules maybe you could give it a chance

https://mevislab.github.io/pythonqt/